# Why windows binaries behave differently on 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have small Qt5-mingw code on my 64 bit machine (Windows 10). In this code i launch a notepad.exe using Qt framework and wait for it to finish its execution. This works fine on both 32bit and 64bit machine.

Now same code is used to launch other exe like calculator. In this case calculator is launched as expected on 32bit platform but on 64 bit we do not wait while the calculator is running.

I have checked this behaviour using process monitor tool on 64bit machine and it seems exe relaunches itself with other `pid`.

**How can i wait for `calc.exe` while it is running?**

```
QProcess notepad;
notepad.start("notepad");
notepad.waitForFinished();
qDebug()<<"notepad will wait for finish";

QProcess calc;
calc.start("calc");  //("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");  ("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\calc.exe");    
// -- wait while finish() --
// 32-bit: Works fine
// 64-bit: This is where we should wait while calc.exe is running    
calc.waitForFinished(); 
qDebug()<<"calculator will NOT wait for finish";
```

Comment: If the issue is that the process you can't keep hold of the process (because it launches a different one and closes itself) then the title is misleading.

Comment: It is no longer calc.exe on Win10.  Now a modern UI program, it relaunches as C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1608.2213.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe on my machine.  Try not to care about that :)